# Jhipster User friend self relationship

Tags: jhipster

I want to create a "friend" relationship  between User using an entity "Friend".
I try this, but it isn't work.

```
entity Friend {
    status Boolean, 
    modified LocalDate,
    created LocalDate
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Friend{user(login)} to User,
    User to Friend{user(login)}
}
```

How i can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :

```
entity UserExtra {
    .....
}
entity Friend{
    status Boolean, 
    modified LocalDate,
    created LocalDate
}
relationship OneToOne {
    UserExtended{user(login)} to User
}

relationship OneToMany {
    UserExtended{friends} to Friend{user}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    UserExtended{friend} to UserExtended{users}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create relationship with `User` entity in JDL

A workaround is to create another entity and use a one-to-one relationship like this

```
entity Friend {
    status Boolean, 
    modified LocalDate,
    created LocalDate
}

entity UserExtended {
    ...
}

relationship OneToOne {
    UserExtended to User
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Friend{userExtended(login)} to UserExtended,
    UserExtended to Friend{userExtended(login)}
}
```

You may want to consider creating the relationship with the `User` directly in the generated code.

Comment: Ok, in JDL we can't create relationship directly with User.